# How to build an edit form for a list of strings in Grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a Grails domain class with a list of strings in it, and I want to edit these strings. For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the list is fixed size. Here's what I have:

MyEntity.groovy:

```
class MyEntity {

    String name
    List variables = ['one', 'two', 'three']

    static hasMany = [
            variables: String,
    ]
}
```

_fields/myEntity/variables/_widget.gsp:

```
<g:textField name="variables[0]" value="${value[0]}" />
<g:textField name="variables[1]" value="${value[1]}" />
<g:textField name="variables[2]" value="${value[2]}" />
```

This renders text fields for each element in the list that are prefilled with the correct values. However, when I edit the values and sumbit the form my edits get discarded. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it myself. The input fields all need to have the name of the domain property, without any index:

```
<g:textField id="variables[0]" name="variables" value="${value[0]}" />
<g:textField id="variables[1]" name="variables" value="${value[1]}" />
<g:textField id="variables[2]" name="variables" value="${value[2]}" />
```